# "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated" Error in flutter

Tags: json, database, flutter, google-chrome, dart

i created a json file with all the data required for my app, it was working fine but one image was showing error saying that it is from another domain, so i changed the image address to another image, and now it says

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

i tried changing it back to the previous image and restarted the application it still shows the error.

```
    {
"id": 1,
"name": "92.7",
"tagline": "on the ground by Rose",
"color": "blue",
"url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/51/Google_Chrome_on_Windows_10_screenshot.png" ,
"icon": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Google_Chrome_icon_%28September_2014%29.svg/96px-Google_Chrome_icon_%28September_2014%29.svg.png" ,
"img": "https://preview.redd.it/ls2yuc4501l61.jpg?width=512&auto=webp&s=be785e98bf288f69c0b0105fb2bce6ab807b20f4",
"category": "blackpink",
"disliked": false,
"order": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "92.7",
"tagline": "blood sweat and tears by BTS",
"color": "blue",
"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/51/Google_Chrome_on_Windows_10_screenshot.png" ,
"icon": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Google_Chrome_icon_%28September_2014%29.svg/96px-Google_Chrome_icon_%28September_2014%29.svg.png",
"img":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTQ3YmU4MjAtYzQ0NC00NjRjLThmMzYtMTE4MzgzMWJkNjliXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDY5MjMyNTg@._V1_.jpg",
"category": "BTS",
"disliked": false,
"order": 2
}
```

Error was in the first pic, the second was showing fine but after changing it , now it doesnt start the application and shows the error i mentioned above. I'm using google chrome to run the application.

Answer (score 10):

Delete your launch.json file as it is causing your app to not launch with the default configuration of flutter

Comment: i havent launch.json, any solutions ?

Comment: I tried deleting my launch.json file but still not working any solutions?

Comment: this worked fine for me

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same error in one of my flutter web projects. you have to delete the launch.json file.
Here is path of file

```
.vscode -> launch.json
```

just `delete launch.json` and your project will run.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "type": "dart"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't just post code with broken format but provide some context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same error in one of my flutter web projects. Then I changed Debug configuration to Flutter(chrome). It worked for me.